# Returning an intersection of two interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am running into a bit of a head scratcher. I have an interface that describes an object which represents some state.

```
export enum Status {
  Pending = 'pending',
  Complete = 'complete',
}

export interface State {
  status: Status
}
```

I also have an interface which basically says it must be in the complete status:

```
export interface CompleteState {
  status: Status.Complete
}
```

Here is where it gets a little trick: The following function must return a sub-type of `State` that also conforms to `CompleteState`:

```
export const fn = <TState extends State>(): (TState & CompleteState) | null => {
  const a = foo<TState>()

  if (a.status === Status.Complete) {
    return a // <--- This line is where the error is
  }

  return null
}
```

In the example above, `foo` is some function that returns a `TState`. The problem is on the line that attempts to return `a`. The error looks sort of like this:

```
Type 'TState' is not assignable to type '(TState & CompleteState) | null'.
  Type 'State' is not assignable to type 'TState & CompleteState'.
    Type 'TState' is not assignable to type 'TState & CompleteState'.
      Type 'State' is not assignable to type 'TState & CompleteState'.
        Type 'State' is not assignable to type 'TState'.
          'State' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TState', but 'TState' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'State'.
            Type 'TState' is not assignable to type 'CompleteState'.
              Type 'State' is not assignable to type 'CompleteState'.
                Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
                  Type 'Status' is not assignable to type 'Status.Complete'.
```

The error seems a little bit strange to me, since `a` must conform to `TState` (we know this since `foo` returns a `TState`) and we know it also must conform to `CompleteState` (since `status` is equal to `Status.Complete`).

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? I can get around this by doing `return a as TState & CompleteState`, but it feels like I'm doing something icky!

Thanks :)

Comment: What is `foo()`?  Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can paste as-is into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing.

Comment: Hmmm it seems that what you want is to return a type that has all the fields of the original state object *except* for `status`, which should be `'complete'`, so as to conform to the `CompleteState`. Am I getting it right?

Comment: I'm guessing this is just [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384) but without a [mre] I can't be sure.